# SQL: Inner join on a Max Times Occurred Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

Posed a question: What school was attended most frequently?

I came up with the following statement...

```
select unitid, count(unitid) as 'Times_Occurred' 
from people 
group by unitid 
order by count(*) desc 
limit 50;
```

I made it limit 50 because multiple unitid's had `3`. I have two tables, a people table, and a post table. They are connected by `unitid`. I am trying to figure out how to do an inner join to get not only the top 50 highest unitid's, and how often they occur, but also the colleges that go along with those Id's.

Any and all help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Wrap the above as an inline view and then join to the post table.  otherwise your counts may get inflated

Comment: What is wrong with your query. Include db shema, sample data and desire output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your counts are being inflated and you don't know how to handle that... this is one approach using an inline view.  The reason this works is because the counts are calculated and retained prior to the join.  Thus the 1-M cardinality doesn't negatively effect the counts.

```
Select * 
from (
  select unitid, count(unitid) as 'Times_Occurred' 
  from people 
  group by unitid 
  order by count(*) desc 
  limit 50) A
INNER JOIN Post  B
  on A.UnitID = B.UnitID
```